# looking for fast way to compute pair wise distances of many strings

Tags: python, distance

I have a list of ~1 million unique 16-character strings (an array called VEC) and I want to calculate the minimum pair-wise hamming distance for each one in Python (an array called RES). Basically, I'm calculating the full pair-wise distance matrix one row at a time but only storing the minimum value in RES for each row.

```
VEC= ['AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA','AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAT','AAAAGAAAAAATAAAA'...]
```

so that dist(VEC[1],VEC[2])=1, dist(VEC[1],VEC[3])=2 etc... and RES[1]=1. Using tips and tricks from these pages I came up with:

```
#METHOD#1:
import Levenshtein
import numpy
RES=99*numpy.ones(len(VEC))
i=0
for a in VEC:
    dist=numpy.array([Levenshtein.hamming(a,b) for b in VEC] ) #array of distances
    RES[i]=numpy.amin(dist[dist>0])  #pick min distance greater than zero
    i+=1
```

a shortened VEC of only 10,000 took about 70 sec, but if I extrapolate that to the full million it will take 8 days.  My approach seems wasteful since I'm recalculating the symmetric parts of the distance matrix so I tried to calculate half of the matrix while updating RES for each row as I went along:

```
#METHOD #2:
import Levenshtein
import numpy
RES=99*numpy.ones(len(VEC))
for i in range(len(VEC)-1):
    dist=[Levenshtein.hamming(VEC[i],VEC[j]) for j in range(i+1, len(VEC))]
    RES[i]=min(numpy.amin(dist),RES[i])
    #update RES as you go along:
    k=0
    for j in range(i+1,len(VEC)):
        if dist[k]<RES[j]:
             RES[j]=dist[k]
        k+=1
```

Probably not surprisingly, this 2nd approach takes almost twice as long (117 sec) so it isn't very good.  Regardless, can anyone recommend improvements/changes to make this faster?

Comment: It's probably going to take a long time one way or another.  You could try to reduce the search space, maybe by calculating the set of characters in each string and not calculating the distance if they're disjoint.  Do you have any extra knowledge about the structure of the strings?  If you do, it might be possible to restrict the search even further.

Comment: Calculate the first pairwise-distance in a given row. Now for all the other distance calculations in the same row, stop it after the distance gets above this initial distance. If it is shorter, update your current minimum and repeat. This doesn't reduce the time-complexity, but might help significantly depending on how your strings are ordered. Also, this problem is simple enough to recode in C and get another constant reduction.

Comment: Also, have you looked at using `scipy.distance`?  It has a hamming distance metric.  I don't know how optimized the Levenshtein library is, but it's possible that you could see a gain by converting your data to a big numpy array and using the scipy tools.

Comment: each string is supposed to random, but I'm looking into some clustering methods. I was hoping that I'd at least be able to get this pared-down version of the distance matrix as a point of comparison.  checking out other distance calculations is a good idea.  Levenshtein.hamming() is definitely faster than my 'for' loop implementation.  The idea to stop calculating each row after you find the first minimum might help.  I sort the strings alphabetically so sometimes similar strings will be next to each other. thanks.

Comment: @jfb I didn't mean to stop at the first local minimum, instead I meant to say that you stop calculating the distance between a pair after it exceeds the current minimum distance. If you can modify your data such that you can use a data-structure like VP-tree and others, then everything is likely to get much faster.

Comment: @mmgp.  Ah, define a 'smart' hamming function that stops comparing a string-pair after the errors exceed the current minimum for that row. It's a good idea. I wonder if I'd be able to define a fast enough function in python?  I can imagine doing it in C though...

Comment: for what it's worth, Levenshtein.hamming() seems to be quite fast, at least compared to the alternates proposed on http://code.activestate.com/recipes/499304-hamming-distance/.  Each of these was at least 10x slower for my problem

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the nearest neighbor for each bitarry (ignoring itself), and you *could* get away with a tiny chance of only getting an approximate nearest neighbor, you might consider implementing the "Bit Sampling" Locality Sensitive Hash for Hamming distance. In a nutshell, create three hash tables. From each 128-bit input, sample 16 bits, 3 times, using those 16 bit samples as keys. The values of your hash tables should be a list of all 128-bit inputs that had that sampled key. Once you place all million of your inputs into the LSH index, simply:

- Iterate over the million points
- For each input, perform the above 3-sampling
- Find the nearest neighbor in each of the three lists (with distance > 0), keep the best overall

Both loading and testing are ludicrously quick. I might recommend the excellent [bitarray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) library for underpinning this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use numpy. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import time

def gen_data(n):
    arr = np.empty(shape=(n, 16))
    for i in range(n):
        arr[i] = np.random.randint(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1, 16)
    return arr

def distance_from_array(i, arr):
    r = arr[i] != arr
    r[i,:] = True
    min_i = np.argmin(np.sum(r, axis=1))
    return min_i

data = gen_data(1000000)
distances = []
start = time.time()
for i in range(200):
    distances.append(distance_from_array(i, data))
end = time.time()
print end - start
```

You can convert your list of strings into an array of numbers. Then you can use numpy function for working with array, such as sum and argmin. I think you don't want to find only distances larger than 1, if it's possible that one string will appear twice.

I tested it on my computer and it takes about 10 seconds to process 200 strings. For each one you have to go through all 1 000 000 other strings, so we can compute the time it would take to process all of them fairly easily. It should be around 13 hours. However, don't forget that we are using only one core at the moment. If you split indexes and use http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool you can get your results quite quickly.